# Widlfy 26 with ActiveMQ "Classic" JCA resource adapter

Tags: java, wildfly, activemq-classic, resource-adapter

I am trying to test an example HelloWorld MDB with Wildfly 26.0.1-Final and ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.16.4.

In `standalone-full.xml`:

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:6.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-termination-period="0" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-termination-period="0" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
            <!-- <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/> -->
            <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
        </subsystem>
```

```xml
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq-rar-5.16.4.rar"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
```

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
            <server name="default">
                <security elytron-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
                <cluster password="${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:CHANGE ME!!}"/>
                <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-d
elay="1000"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-acceptor>
                <jgroups-broadcast-group name="bg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <jgroups-discovery-group name="dg-group1" jgroups-cluster="activemq-cluster"/>
                <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" discovery-group="dg-group1"/>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

```xml
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="activemq-rar-5.16.4.rar">
                    <archive>
                        activemq-rar-5.16.4.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <config-property name="ServerUrl">tcp://localhost:61616?soTimeout=20000&amp;connectionTimeout=10000</config-property>
                    <config-property name="UserName">admin</config-property>
                    <config-property name="UseInboundSession">false</config-property>
                    <config-property name="Password">admin</config-property>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory" use-ccm="true">
                            <xa-pool>
                                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                                <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
                            </xa-pool>
                            <timeout>
                                <blocking-timeout-millis>30000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                                <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                            </timeout>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                    <admin-objects>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="HELLOWORLDMDBQueue">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">HELLOWORLDMDBQueue</config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic" jndi-name="java:/topic/HELLOWORLDMDBTopic" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="HELLOWORLDMDBTopic">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">HELLOWORLDMDBTopic</config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                    </admin-objects>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

After I put the `activemq-rar-5.16.4.rar` in the `deployments` folder I started Wildfly with

```
./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml
```

Now I want to try with an helloworld-mdb

```java
@WebServlet("/HelloWorldMDBServletClient")
public class HelloWorldMDBServletClient extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8314035702649252239L;

    private static final int MSG_COUNT = 5;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

```java
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter;
/**
 * <p>
 * A simple Message Driven Bean that asynchronously receives and processes the messages that are sent to the topic.
 * </p>
 *
 * @author Serge Pagop (spagop@redhat.com)
 */
@MessageDriven(name = "HelloWorldQTopicMDB", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBTopic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")})
@ResourceAdapter(value="activemq-rar-5.16.4.rar")
public class HelloWorldTopicMDB implements MessageListener {
```

Done the war, I am trying to deploy into Wildfly but I give an error:

```
09:44:53,938 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."helloworld-mdb.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."helloworld-mdb.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "helloworld-mdb.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.naming.deployment.ContextNames.bindInfoFor(ContextNames.java:351)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.JMSConnectionFactoryDefinitionInjectionSource.getDefaulResourceAdapter(JMSConnectionFactoryDefinitionInjectionSource.java:428)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.deployment.JMSDestinationDefinitionInjectionSource.getResourceValue(JMSDestinationDefinitionInjectionSource.java:137)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.addJndiBinding(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:294)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:242)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:246)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:160)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
    ... 8 more

09:44:53,941 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "helloworld-mdb.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"helloworld-mdb.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".WeldStartService",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".WeldStartService]"
    ]
}
09:44:53,942 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "helloworld-mdb.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"helloworld-mdb.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".WeldStartService",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".WeldStartService]"
    ]
}
09:44:53,942 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "helloworld-mdb.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"helloworld-mdb.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".WeldStartService",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".beanmanager, jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloworld-mdb.war\".WeldStartService]"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your servlet is using `java:/ConnectionFactory`, but that JNDI name is bound by the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis broker. Did you mean to use `java:/ActiveMQ/QueueConnectionFactory` instead? This connection factory is bound by the ActiveMQ JCA RA.

Comment: In your `standalone-full.xml` you're setting `<resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq-rar-5.16.4.rar"/>` which means your MDB doesn't need `@ResourceAdapter(value="activemq-rar-5.16.4.rar")`.

Comment: Why not just use the embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis? If you don't need it then you should almost certainly remove it from your `standalone-full.xml`.

Comment: Your MDB is using `java:/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBTopic`, but that JNDI binding doesn't exist anywhere. You should almost certainly use either `java:/topic/HELLOWORLDMDBTopic` or `java:/queue/HELLOWORLDMDBQueue`.